# Upgrading Oracle XE from 11g to 21c broke Django's ability to talk to TNS Listener

Tags: python, django, oracle

I have an old application that is running django 1.10 with an oracle XE 11g back end. We are trying to upgrade the XE to 21c.

The issue is that django cannot find the TNS listener even though it is there and running. sqlplus works correctly so there is no issue with the listener itself.

The django application and the XE database are both running on the same server so there is no networking issue.

The main change as far as I can tell between the 11g and 21c is that the newer oracle database has plugin databases and needs to be addressed via the easy connect naming mechanism. Is that supported by django 1.10?

Directly using cx_Oracle to connect to the database from python3 also works without throwing errors.

Any pointers appreciated.

Updated with more information as requested:
The settings.py in django defines the DB section as:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'centos8/XEPDB1'
        'PORT' : '1521',
        'HOST' : '127.0.0.1',
        'USER' : 'raxak3',
        'PASSWORD' : '*****', #blanked for security
        'CONN_MAX_AG' : None,
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'threaded' : True,
        }
    } }
```

I have tried setting the name in various ways: @centos8/XEPDB1, //centos8/XEPDB1, etc. but cannot figure out the right way to address the DB.

Using sqlplus works:

> (raxak) [raxak@centos8 raxak]$ sqlplus raxak3@centos8/XEPDB1
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Dec 3 13:26:01 2021
> Version 21.3.0.0.0
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Enter password:  Last Successful login time: Tue Nov 30 2021 12:03:30
> -05:00
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 -
> Production Version 21.3.0.0.0
>
> SQL>

The listener is alive and well:

> [root@centos8 dbhomeXE]# lsnrctl status
>
> LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 03-DEC-2021
> 13:27:21
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connecting to
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=centos8)(PORT=1521))) STATUS
> of the LISTENER
> ------------------------ Alias                     LISTENER Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production Start Date
> 30-NOV-2021 11:48:06 Uptime                    3 days 1 hr. 39 min. 14
> sec Trace Level               off Security                  ON: Local
> OS Authentication SNMP                      OFF Default Service
> XE Listener Parameter File
> /opt/oracle/homes/OraDBHome21cXE/network/admin/listener.ora Listener
> Log File
> /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/centos8/listener/alert/log.xml Listening
> Endpoints Summary...
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=centos8)(PORT=1521)))
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/opt/oracle/admin/XE/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
> Services Summary... Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).   Instance "XE",
> status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... Service "XEXDB" has
> 1 instance(s).   Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for
> this service... Service "d1f80698dc870fb5e0555054000661f1" has 1
> instance(s).   Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this
> service... Service "xepdb1" has 1 instance(s).   Instance "XE", status
> READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... The command completed
> successfully

But running from django gives this error:

> (raxak) [raxak@centos8 raxak]$ python3 manage.py migrate Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 199, in ensure_connection
> self.connect()   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 171, in connect
> self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py",
> line 216, in get_new_connection
> return Database.connect(conn_string, **conn_params) cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in
>
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 367, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
> line 359, in execute
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 305, in run_from_argv
> self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 353, in execute
> self.check()   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 385, in check
> include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py",
> line 62, in _run_checks
> issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 372, in _run_checks
> return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py",
> line 81, in run_checks
> new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py",
> line 14, in check_url_config
> return check_resolver(resolver)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py",
> line 24, in check_resolver
> for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
> line 35, in **get**
> res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
> line 310, in url_patterns
> patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
> "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
> line 35, in **get**
> res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
> line 303, in urlconf_module
> return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in
> import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
> File "", line 678, in
> exec_module   File "", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "/u01/rp/raxak/raxakprotect/urls.py", line 22, in 
> from users.views import RaxakManage, Terms   File "/u01/rp/raxak/users/views.py", line 40, in 
> from common import appdetails   File "/u01/rp/raxak/common/appdetails.py", line 17, in 
> from resources.views import code_version   File "/u01/rp/raxak/resources/views.py", line 38, in 
> from .helper_functions import *   File "/u01/rp/raxak/resources/helper_functions.py", line 38, in 
> cursor = connection.cursor()   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 233, in cursor
> cursor = self.make_cursor(self._cursor())   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 204, in _cursor
> self.ensure_connection()   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 199, in ensure_connection
> self.connect()   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
> line 94, in **exit**
> six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py",
> line 685, in reraise
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 199, in ensure_connection
> self.connect()   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 171, in connect
> self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py",
> line 216, in get_new_connection
> return Database.connect(conn_string, **conn_params) django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: Please update your question with the error message and how django is configured for connecting to the database.

Comment: You can connect to PDBs from Django.  Try setting your DATABASES entry like `'NAME':     'localhost/XEPDB1'`  Or set up a tnsnames.ora file and use the network alias from the file.

Comment: Added error message trail to the original message. Appreciate any help. Of course the plan is to upgrade django itself to 3.x but want the basic switch to the DB working before we start worrying about dependencies in the django side code.

Comment: In DATABASES delete the HOST and PORT entries.  See step 6 of the very old tutorial https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/python_django/python_django.htm  (If needed, these values would be included in the 'easy connect' string used in the NAME)  Also perhaps change the NAME to match the one I gave, or use 127.0.0.1 for the hostname part, e.g. `127.0.0.1/XEPDB1`.

Comment: Tried that. with all combinations of hostname being 127.0.0.1, centos8 (the linux hostname for the system), localhost, etc.

All get the same error: TNS:no listner

Comment: In the exact same shell that you are running Python, use SQL*Plus (not sqlcl or SQL Developer which use a Java stack) and get that connected.  That will confirm the connect string.  Also make sure the Oracle network listener is actually running - use `lsnrctl`

Comment: The trace above shows sql*plus in the same shell and the lsnrct in the same shell. And both run fine. I also (re)checked that LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH have the appropriate links: LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/lib/oracle/19.13/client64/lib:/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/lib and PATH = /usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin:/home/raxak/.virtualenvs/raxak/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/bin

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the issue:

I had a prod.py and a dev.py in settings, and since I was only invoking the prod.py I did not notice that dev.py still had the older, non PDB addressing in the DATABASES definition. Usually both these are identical. All changes I was testing with in prod were being silently being overridden.

Found the issue by putting print statements in

/home/raxak/.virtualenvs//lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py

just before the Database.connect(..) statement in get_new_connection(..) to see what it was trying to connect with.

The final DATABASES definition that worked was:

```html
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',                                   
        'NAME' : '127.0.0.1:1521/XEPDB1',
        'PORT' : '',
        'HOST' : '',
        'USER' : <username>,
        'PASSWORD' : <password>,
        'CONN_MAX_AGE' : None,
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'threaded' : True,
        }
    }
```

Thanks to all who helped, particularly Christopher Jones,